# Displaying "Content Updated/Revised" Notice with PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime

Checking datetime differences with PHP and if **post date** and **update date** do not match return a notice banner indicating the content was updated on **update date**

Would this be a way to go about it.

```
function content_update_notice() {

   $post_date = strtotime($row['postdate']);
   $update_on = strtotime($row['updatedate']);

   if($post_date != $updated_on) {

      $alert = "Post has been updated on ".$update_on;

   } else { }
}
```

But here is a little dilemma, if the $update_on is older than 10 days then remove the notice.

How would I go about it, and is my function valid?

[image]

Comment: What did you try/investigate?

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime` is a powerful way to manipulate dates. In this case:

```
function content_update_notice ($row) {
    $post_date = new DateTime($row['postdate']);
    $update_on = new DateTime($row['updatedate']);

    if ($post_date != $update_on) {
        $difference = $post_date->diff($update_on);

        if ($difference->d < 10) {
            return 'Post has been updated on ' . $update_on->format('F jS, Y');
        }
    }
}
```